# How to save the user entity along with the images in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some fields in my entity like name , email , password , address and byte[] images for images , how can I save the user object along with the images in spring boot ?
Is there any way to take the user object along with the images in request body ?

Your answer will be highly appreciate

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example ?https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-db-storing-files However there are thousand of example out there. Just google it.